# User registration through service

Tags: users, services

I have a local Drupal instance with services. I created an endpoint that has user resource included. I verified that all is well by logging in using the endpoint. I am now stuck at registering new users through the api. I tried the following:

URL: http://localhost/recipes/api/user/register

Method: POST

Content-Type: application/json

Body: 
    {
   "name":"user34",
   "pass":"3323",
   "mail":"sample@example.com",
   "status":"1"
}

Result: 22:CSRF validation failed

I know that this error pops out when the token is not passed in the header of the request but how am I supposed to get the token if I am an anonymous user wanting to register?

Kindly mention the steps that I need to follow to have a user register through the REST api

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anonymous (and authenticated) users can both get the token from the same place. Try following these steps:

1. Get the token with a `GET` to `?q=services/session/token`
2. Attach the token to your `POST` header under the name `X-CSRF-Token`
3. Make the `POST` call to register the user

Comment: I tried making a get request to http://localhost/recipes/api/session/token and using postman, the response had no content in the body. However, if I look at the cookies in the response I can see a key/value pair of a random string. That said, should I use the string in the value of the cookie as the value of the X-CSRF-Token in my next request? Thanks

Comment: The `services/session/token` path is reserved, and does not include your api endpoint path. So don't use `api/session/token` for the token, instead always use `services/session/token`.